# Generating a good LDA model of Twitter in Python with correct input data

Tags: python, twitter, lda, gensim, topic-modeling

I'm dealing with topic-modelling of Twitter to define profiles of invidual Twitter users. I'm using Gensim module to generate a LDA model. My question is about choosing good input data. I'd like to generate topics which then I'd assign to specific users. Question is about input data. Now I'm using a supervised method of choosing users from different categories on my own (sports, IT, politics etc) and putting their tweets into the model but it's not very efficient and effective.

What would be a good method for generating meaningful topics of the whole Twitter?

Comment: Note that a topic from topic modeling is something different from a label or a class in a classification task. Make sure that you understand well the terms you are using and think about your question again. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one profiling that I used to perform when I worked for a social media company.
Let's say you want to profile "sports" followers.
First, using Twitter API, download all the followers of one famous sports handle, say "ESPN". Looks like this:

```
       "ESPN": 51879246, #These are IDs who follow ESPN
              2361734293,
              778094964,
              23000618,
              2828513313,
              2687406674,
              2402689721,
              2209802017,
```

Then you also download all handles that `51879246, 2361734293...` are following. Those "topics" will be your features.

Now all you need to do is to create the matrix X whose size is same as the number of features * number of followers. Then start filling that Matrix with 1 whenever that follower follows the specific topic(feature) in your feature dictionary.

Then here are simple 2 lines to start playing with.

```
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=5, n_iter=1000, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)
```